# octave gui : typing text in command window is not visible

Tags: 14.04, octave

Hi I am student and I heard about octave gui 
I used the command `octave --force-gui` when I had version 3.8
and while typing in command window I was not able to see the text.
Cursor was there but no text is to be seen.

I thought this could be a problem with the Ubuntu theme, but I tried different themes and still no luck. I  opened configuration pop up and made any kind of setting  but still no luck.

Yesterday I download the last octave release (octave 4.0) and thought the problem will no more occur, but unfortunately same problem remains.

I have the feeling it is not a octave problem but a Ubuntu 14.04 problem because  octave gui works well in windows OS (I tested it).

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior: is the command window functional in spite of the invisible text e.g. if you enter and execute a command (such as `version`) does it subsequently appear in the command history window?

Comment: Do you have proper permissions?
It was not working properly when I started octave as root user but worked just fine when started through single user mode.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact problem on with Octave 3.8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04

This saved me:

```
sudo apt-get install octave-strings
```

Thank you to steeldriver who mentioned octave-strings in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627383/gnu-octaves-legend-function-is-broken)!