# GNU Octave Command Window not working

Tags: command-line, window, octave

I installed GNU Octave a few days ago. Until today,it was working fine. But today, its command window is not working,sometimes it makes whole program freeze. I have searched why it is like that. In this forum, I saw a question about this situation (*[octave gui : typing text in command window is not visible](https://askubuntu.com/questions/630826/octave-gui-typing-text-in-command-window-is-not-visible)*). I did the instructions,but still it doesn't work.
How can i solve this problem ? (I delete and reinstall the program).

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Don't add [SOLVED] to the title. Write an answer instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing and reinstalling the Qt Creator.

In my searches on the Internet, it may be caused by Qt Creator, and when I did the reinstalling operation, it is solved and now, works fine.