# Octave 3.8.1 on Ubuntu 14.04: command line does not show text

Tags: 14.04, octave

I have installed Octave 3.8.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 (64bits). I can open Octave GUI but the command window isn't working well.
If I write a command it is executed but I can't see anything in the command window.

I tried to install QtCreator, as recommended here: [GNU Octave Command Window not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802815/gnu-octave-command-window-not-working)
and I also tried to install octave-strings ([octave gui : typing text in command window is not visible](https://askubuntu.com/questions/630826/octave-gui-typing-text-in-command-window-is-not-visible)), but I can't fix the problem.

Is there any other suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried updating to the latest version of Octave? It's now at 4.0.3 so you may be encountering bugs from the older version.

Comment: I first installed the 4.0.2 version and I had the same problem, so I installed this version. Do you recommend to uninstall and install the latest version?

Comment: I just upgraded to the 4.0.2 version and the problem is still there.

Comment: I am guessing there is some configuration setting for octave that is incorrect causing that to happen. Try purging Octave. If you run Synaptic package manager, that will be right-clicking on the package and selecting Mark for Complete Removal or in the terminal `sudo purge octave`. Then try re-installing. It is working for me quite well in Ubuntu 16.04 so the other option is to simply upgrade Ubuntu to the latest LTS release.

Comment: I just tried but with the same problem. Could it be a matter of permissions? I have to write sudo octave to open it.

Answer (score 1):

It was a matter of permissions. I changed them and the problem is solved.
Nevertheless, I am not sure what I exactly did. I changed the permissions for /home/.config/octave directory.

Comment: What commands did you run to change the permissions?

Comment: Glad to know you figured it out. Generally speaking, GUI programs don't need to be launched with `sudo` except for tools which need access to the root filesystem.

Comment: @edwinksl I moved it to my ownership with `sudo chown daimyokirby:daimyokirby`. This didn't fix it for me, though, but deleting the octave folder did.